# A menu with a rare white line, help please

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I have a css problem. 
I would like the white border between the 
"end" of the screen away it really is against it.

Jsfiddle: 
http://goo.gl/KL5iYJ

Comment: I don't get what you're asking.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Use your developer tools to figure out which element is creating the space...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the top border by setting the body's padding and margin to 0, like such:

```
body {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

This will eliminate the whitespace above and to the sides of your menu.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you're asking, but I'm guessing this simple block solves what you are attempting to reach

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put in your css:

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Careful; check your syntax at the end of margin!